# access all resource information inside resource group terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am building terraform module and using many places existing resource group and storage account. Is there any way to import storage account details, while importing resource group only. otherwsie I have to repeat the mentioned code in all modules.

````
or anyway like ```data "azurerm_resource_group" "name"{Access storage account}"```

data "azurerm_resource_group" "name" {
     name = "rgroup"
  }

   data "azurerm_storage_account" "staccount" {
     name                = "stg"
     resource_group_name = "rgroup"
   }
````

Answer (score 1):

No there is not a way to do that. You could make your own module that does that and reuse that one module to return the output you need.

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the direction. Could you please have a look at the below question, I got stuck completely and not able to proceed further.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58984760/