# terraform module depends_on Azure

Tags: azure, terraform, devops

I am building a production infrastructure in Azure cloud with terraform. My requirements are below.

Azure key vault should be provision first, as I will utilize a secret from there. But as terraform module doesn't support depend_on. Any workaround will be highly appricaiable.

```
     source    = "./../modules/azurekeyvault/"
     username =  "${var.username}"
     tags_environment    = "${var.tags_environment}"
   }

   module "mysql" {
     source                             = "./../modules/mysql/"
   }
```

Azure key vault module.

```
  name                        = "${var.lsrkeyvault}"
  location                    = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.lsr.location}"
  resource_group_name         = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.lsr.name}"
  enabled_for_disk_encryption = true
  tenant_id           = "${data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id}" 

  sku_name = "standard
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "userlist" {
  count = length(var.username)
  name  = "${var.username[count.index]}"
  value =  "${bcrypt(random_string.password.result)}" 
  key_vault_id = "${azurerm_key_vault.kvlsr.id}"
  tags = {
    environment = "${var.tags_environment}"
  }
}
```

Mysql Module code:

```
    name                            =  "kyv-lsr-dev"
    resource_group_name = "rgroup"
   }

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "userlist" {
      name         = "mylab"
      key_vault_id = "${data.azurerm_key_vault.keyvault.id}"
```

Comment: i'd provision the key vault and such seperatly, with their own state for that matter, then just use the vault to pass secrets and such.
That's what I did, let me know if you want me to show you how

Comment: @Naim thanks for answer but in this case I have to maintain 2 separate state files. I want with a single state file all infrastructure should provisions. Please show your code

Comment: hi https://stackoverflow.com/users/10870934/vijay-verma, if you can edit your question to show the mysql module, I can quickly write a code example to answer your needs

Comment: how to implement a depends_on for modules see https://medium.com/mineiros/the-ultimate-guide-on-how-to-write-terraform-modules-part-1-81f86d31f024

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this would work, but here is what I would recommend trying to help TF build out the correct dependency graph. I would make the keyvault id a variable in your module. That way when you use the module you will be explicitly calling the keyvault which should trigger it to be created before the module is executed.

```
 module "mysql" {
     source      = "./../modules/mysql/"
     keyvault_id = "${module.keyvault.id}"                    
 }
```

This would require your mysql module to take keyvault_id as a variable and use that instead of the data resoruce. It would also require your keyvault module to output the keyvault id.  Again, this may not work, but I think it will.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am calling azurerm_key_vault_secret also as a data source in MySQL block. In this case how secret value will be populated. 

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "userlist" {
     name         = "mysqladminun"
      key_vault_id = "${data.azurerm_key_vault.keyvault.id}"                                                        
        }
        
  }

  administrator_login          = "mysqladminun"
  administrator_login_password = "${azurerm_key_vault_secret.userlist.value}"
  version                      = "5.7"`

Comment: you should be fine calling the secret there because you will have the id passed it.  If the keyvault exists the secret should, correct?

Comment: thanks i am pasting demo code , can u check below code:
https://codeshare.io/5zWB4O